# Add "Help text" for standard contact fields

Tags: standard-objects

I want to add help text for "Mailing Address" and "Other Address" standard fields in Contact Object. But those fields are not editable by default (Except setting FLS). Kindly help me to accomplish this.

Thanks In Anticipation,
Karthik

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done via the Force.com UI for the Address fields. [Other standard fields were supported in Winter 10 release](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpapAAC)

However, you can do a few things that might mitigate the need for hover help

- Change the label for the fields using `Setup | Rename Tabs and Labels`
- Use State and Country picklist feature so only valid states and countries can be chosen
- Use validation rules to 'cure' the user of doing bad things

If this were super important, you could always replace the page with VF and provide your own hover help.  But I suspect that isn't worth doing for something so conceptually understandable as an address.